# What does empty string ε actually mean?

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

I came across this weird expression while learning about regular expressions.

$R^+ \cup \varepsilon = R^*$

why does doing union with an empty string makes this regex go from 1 or more to 0 or more?

Comment: There is a bit of an abuse of notations between the empty string, the regular expression that matches just the empty string, and the singleton set that contains only the empty string.

Comment: It looks like you've gotten help that worked for you, which is great. But in the future, you may get better answers if you explain a bit more about what's going on in your head. Answering a question of the form "Why does X happen?" requires much more guesswork about what's gone wrong with your reasoning than "Why does X happen? I expected Y to happen instead." does.

Comment: sure @DanielWagner I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Compare the equivalent POSIX notation: `(.+)|()` = `.*`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regular expressions represent sets of strings, so $\varepsilon$ in that expression represents the set that contain only the 0 length string, $\{\varepsilon\} $. This of course is not the same as the empty set $\emptyset$, so the union will add the empty string to the set that does not contain an empty string ($R^+$) , hence the regular expression $R^*$ is the set of strings that contains 0 length (empty) string and non-zero length string.